# How can I get the author of each post in the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT id,
       subject,
       category cat,
       keywords tags,
       body_html, amount,
       date_time,
       (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0)
          FROM votes vv
          WHERE qanda.id = vv.post_id and 15 = vv.table_code) AS total_votes,
       (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vt.total_viewed),0)
          FROM viewed_total vt
          WHERE qanda.id = vt.post_id and 15 = vt.table_code limit 1) AS total_viewed
FROM qanda WHERE type = 0 $query_where
ORDER BY $query_order
LIMIT :j,11;
```

It provides a list *(maximum 10 cases)* of posts. Now I need to also get the author's name of each post. How can I do that?

My tables structure look like this:

```
// users
+----+--------+-----------------+--------
| id |  name  |      email      |  ....
+----+--------+-----------------+--------

// qanda
+----+------------+-----------------------+-----------+--------
| id |    title   |          body         | author_id |  ....
+----+------------+-----------------------+-----------+--------
-- author_id refers to the id column of users table
```

I can add one more sub query to get author's name for each post. But I think using `join` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need  a inner join woth users

```
  SELECT a.id,
         a.subject,
         a.category cat,
         a.keywords tags,
         a.body_html, 
         a.amount,
         a.date_time,
         u.name 
         (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0)
            FROM votes vv
            WHERE qanda.id = vv.post_id and 15 = vv.table_code) AS total_votes,
         (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vt.total_viewed),0)
            FROM viewed_total vt
            WHERE qanda.id = vt.post_id and 15 = vt.table_code limit 1) AS total_viewed
  FROM qanda a 
  INNER JOIN users u on a.id = u.author_id
  WHERE type = 0 $query_where
  ORDER BY $query_order
  LIMIT :j,11;
```

and if some post have not author you must use left join

```
    SELECT a.id,
         a.subject,
         a.category cat,
         a.keywords tags,
         a.body_html, 
         a.amount,
         a.date_time,
         u.name 
         (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0)
            FROM votes vv
            WHERE qanda.id = vv.post_id and 15 = vv.table_code) AS total_votes,
         (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vt.total_viewed),0)
            FROM viewed_total vt
            WHERE qanda.id = vt.post_id and 15 = vt.table_code limit 1) AS total_viewed
  FROM qanda a 
  LEFT JOIN users u on a.id = u.author_id
  WHERE type = 0 $query_where
  ORDER BY $query_order
  LIMIT :j,11;
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. Just are you sure `INNER JOIN`? Since some posts don't have any author. I guess `LEFT JOIN` would be better. Am I right?

Comment: Answer  updated ... left join if  not all post have users